# Adding new reclassified column to attribute table in QGIS using "CASE", "WHEN" "THEN"

Tags: qgis

I am stuck by adding new column (kg/ha) based on "Value" table with using following. This is an NDVI layer which I want to convert to prescription map for variable rate fertilization. I tried following:

```
case
when"VALUE" <= 0 then 20
when"VALUE"= 0-0.05 then 30
when"VALUE"= 0.05-0.10 then 45
when"VALUE"= 0.10-0.15 then 130
when"VALUE"= 0.15-0.20 then 125
when"VALUE"= 0.20-0.25 then 120
when"VALUE"= 0.25-0.30 then 110
when"VALUE"= 0.30-0.35 then 95
when"VALUE"= 0.35-0.40 then 85
when"VALUE"= 0.40-0.45 then 80
when"VALUE"= 0.45-0.50 then 75
when"VALUE"= 0.50-0.55 then 70
when"VALUE"= 0.55-0.60 then 65
when"VALUE"= 0.60-0.65 then 60
when"VALUE"= 0.65-0.70 then 55
when"VALUE"= 0.70-0.75 then 50
when"VALUE"= 0.75-0.80 then 45
when"VALUE"= 0.80-0.85 then 40
when"VALUE"= 0.85-0.90 then 35
when"VALUE"= 0.95-0.95 then 30
when"VALUE">=0.95 then 25
end
```

but the result is only "NULL". Can someone tell me what I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Your values ('50-60') do not exist and arent numbers. Try e.g. when "value"  >= 50 and "value" < 60 then 70

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick feedback. just found the right formula :):

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick feedback. Seems like I found a solution by the time. case
when"VALUE" <= 0 then 20
when"VALUE" <= 0.05 then 30
when"VALUE" <= 0.10 then 45
when"VALUE" <= 0.15 then 130
when"VALUE" <= 0.20 then 125
when"VALUE" <= 0.25 then 120
when"VALUE" <= 0.30 then 110
when"VALUE" <= 0.35 then 95
when"VALUE" <= 0.40 then 85... end. This one works well :)